# Standard Email Contact Form produces "The action you have requested is invalid" error. How can this be fixed?

Tags: email-contact-form

I have basically copied and pasted the example email contact form from the ExpressionEngine 2.9.2 User Guide (https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/email/contact_form.html) and it is coming with the error:

> The action you have requested is invalid

Here is the code in question:

```
{exp:email:contact_form user_recipients="no" recipients="gabrielthornton@guicreative.com" charset="utf-8" replyto="yes"}
<p>
    <label for="from">Your Email:</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="from" name="from" size="40" maxlength="35" value="{member_email}" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="subject">Subject:</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" size="40" value="Contact Form" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="message">Message:</label><br />
    <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="18" cols="40">
        Support Email from: {member_name}
        Sent at:  {current_time format="%Y %m %d"}
    </textarea>
</p>
<p>
    <input name="submit" type='submit' value='Submit Form' />
</p>
<input type='hidden' name='XID' value='{XID_HASH}' />
{/exp:email:contact_form}
```

I have searched for answers and come up with the secure form XID bug. As a result I have, as you can see above, included the following code to send a valid XID code with the form.

```
<input type='hidden' name='XID' value='{XID_HASH}' />
```

However, the problem still persists. Does anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks

Gabe

Comment: Can you confirm that the "Email" module is installed?

Comment: Yup, it's installed.